# How to filter Pandas DataFrame by checking whether a Column contains any String from a List?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

**Context**

I have a `Pandas` `DataFrame` and would like to filter it by only including `Rows` that contain any `String` from a given `List`. However, I can't find a solution in the `Pandas` `Documentation`.

---

**Code**

DataFrame

```
ID      Names
0       'NameA NameB'
1       'NameB'
2       'NameB NameC'
3       'NameC'
```

```py
data: pandas.DataFrame = ...
names = ['NameA', 'NameC']

filteredData = data.filter ... # ?
```

> In this example, when filtering, only the `Row` with `ID = 1` should be removed, since it does not contain one the defined `Names`.

---

**Question**

- How can I achieve the described goal above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
df2=data.loc[data['Names'].str.contains('|'.join(names))]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, how can `.join` do the trick when the output looks like this: `NameA|NameC`, which is a `String`, none of the `Rows` actually contains?

Comment: "**|**" operator means **or**. like this:  NameA or NameC...

Comment: I know, however, I didn't know that `.contains` supports this inside a `String`.